# Consider the following (unrealistic!) investment issue

Tags: algorithm, return, complexity-theory, pseudocode

Consider the following (unrealistic!) investment problem.

We have a set S of n potential investments, each given by a pair of floating point numbers (amount, estimated return)  There is a total amount A to invest; we want to select investments to maximise the return on this amount.

One may select each investment (a,r) as a whole (spending all of a, and getting r return) or only can select only a fraction f (spending (f*a), and getting (f*r) return). The estimated return of a set of selections is the sum of the returns of the individual selections. Obviously, in selecting elements of S, we cannot spend more than the total amount A available.

Describe an efficient algorithm for computing the maximum estimated return that can be realised with amount A and set of investments S. What is the time complexity of your algorithm (in big-oh notation)?

Is it the best possible?

It is fine to describe your algorithm in words and/or pseudocode; there's no need to include code in a programming language.

Comment: Well I researched whatever I could and I figured out that all the selections in the set could be sorted according to their return value and then the investment amount can be selected according to their return values. But I am stumped after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [fractional knapsack problem](http://www.csee.wvu.edu/~ksmani/courses/fa05/aoa/qen/fk.pdf), which, unlike its integer counterpart, is luckily easy to solve for an optimal solution with a greedy algorithm.

1. start by ordering the investments according to the decreasing ratio r/a
2. allocate your available money to the investments in such order. I.e. buy all the first investment, then use available money to buy the second investment, then the third, etc, until you have finished the money.

As for complexity, you have O(n) for calculating the ratios, O(n logn) for sorting the investments and O(n) for allocating the money. This means the algorithm on the whole is O(n logn).

Comment: Thanks a lot man! That was of great help! :)

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer if you think it answers your question. :-)